# How to Swipe Horizontally using appium

Tags: java, android, appium, swipe, appium-desktop

[image: # screen unable to swipe]

I have 5 swipe screens and my code just stuck at 3rd screen i want to scroll Horizontally.

Comment: This is my screen dimensions
App window dimensions -> (720, 1280)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: public static void swipe(){
  Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        System.out.println("App window dimensions -> " + size);
        //swiping from right to left
        driver.swipe(size.width-1,  size.height/2, 1,  size.height/2, 200);
 }

Comment: @AhmedAliQAEngineer [Edit] your code into your question.

Comment: Put this code in your question body NOT here in comments

Comment: i am unable to edit this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below method for swiping horizontally:

```
public static void swipeHorizontal(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
            Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
            int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
            int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
            int endPoint = (int) (size.width * finalPercentage);
            new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(endPoint, anchor).release().perform();
        }
```

Call the above method by:

```
swipeHorizontal((AppiumDriver) driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,2000);
```

Comment: Ok let me try this

Comment: Can I use this function for multi-screens ?

Comment: `for(int i=0 ; i<=4;i++){
   
  Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
        int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
        int endPoint = (int) (size.width * finalPercentage);
        new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor).waitAction().moveTo(endPoint, anchor).release().perform();
  }`

Comment: but its running very fast and quick

Comment: Thread.sleep(3000);
   swipeHorizontal((AppiumDriver) driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,5000);

Comment: `swipeHorizontal((AppiumDriver) driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,5000); Thread.sleep(3000); `

Answer (score 2):

here is code that has proven good to me:

```
enum DIRECTION{UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT};
```

and:

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction){
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height /2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            break;

        case UP:
            endY= (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY  = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);

            break;

    }

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(startX, startY)
            .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
            .moveTo(endX, startY)
            .release()
            .perform();

}
```

Hope it helps...